# Mean of Date in Column with Pandas and Imputer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a 'Date' column in my dataset which has missing values. I want to take the mean of that column and as of now I have tried this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv') 
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='Nan',strategy ='mean',axis=0)
imputer=imputer.fit(df[:,16]) 
df[:,16]=imputer.transform(df[:,16])
```

This gives me an error unhashable type slice. Can anyone give their inputs on what is the correct way to take mean of dates in a column?

Comment: please add an sample of your dataeset

Comment: What's an average of dates? Are you looking for number of days?

Comment: Please provide a [minimum, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem and expected output.

Comment: This might help explain your error message https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2c6iu8/question_in_python_27_why_are_slices_unhashable/

Answer (score 0):

One way to take the mean of a bunch of dates is to first convert to Julian Dates.

In Pandas, with a date-index dataframe that can be done as:

```
dat['Julian_date']=dat.index.to_julian_date()

mean_date=dat.Julian_date.mean()
```

Then you then need to convert julian date back to pandas date-time, which isn't too hard. There is probably a better way, but I made a hacky function that works to get it from julian to decimal date, just fine for my purposes:

```
def decimal_date_from_julian(JD):
    L= JD+68569
    N= 4*L/146097
    L= L-(146097*N+3)/4
    I= 4000*(L+1)/1461001
    L= L-1461*I/4+31
    J= 80*L/2447
    K= L-2447*J/80
    L= J/11
    J= J+2-12*L
    decimal_date= 100*(N-49)+I+L
    return(decimal_date)

print(decimal_date_from_julian(mean_date))
```

Good luck.